# MySQL Multiple Where Conditions on Same Field in a Join

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table called "orders" with

```
order_id
customer_name
item
```

and am joining it to another table called "orders_requests" containing

```
order_id
requests
```

One row in "orders" may have zero or more rows in "order_requests." I'm trying to perform a query to find "orders" that have "orders_requests" of "rush processing" and "free shipping." I'm leaning towards a RIGHT OUTER JOIN with the "orders_requests" table on the left so it only returns results if a corresponding "orders" row exists, but I've had no success with either of these queries.

This one doesn't work since it pulls rows that are rush processing or free shipping.

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.order_id, orders.* , 
FROM orders_requests
RIGHT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders_requests.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE orders_requests.requests
IN ('rush processing', 'free shipping')
```

And this one clearly doesn't work since it's impossible for any one row to match both conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.order_id, orders.* , 
FROM orders_requests
RIGHT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders_requests.order_id = orders.order_id
WHERE orders_requests.requests = 'rush processing'
AND orders_requests.requests = 'free shipping'
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with my table setup do I need to change the structure?

Comment: The first query looks ok, `x IN (a,b)` just means `x=a OR x=b` how is this not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this would work since I cannot test it atm but try this:

```
select a.order_id, b.*, c.*
from orders a 
left outer join orders_requests b on b.order_id = a.order_id
left outer join orders_requests c on c.order_id = a.order_id
where b.requests = 'rush processing' and c.requests = 'free shipping'
```